# PowerBI: How to calculate/convert Time into Percentage using DAX/Measure

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

I managed to get in Excel desired **% of time difference** from column E, easy job just changed the Data Type to Percentage. What are we calculating is % of these TimeDifferences, one per one (other columns inconsiderable).

The same thing isn't in PowerBI, where I am not able to calculate it properly, always getting "1" before comma and then the result - you can compare it in both tables/columns what I am talking about.

I am looking for the way/DAX/measure how to properly calculate it, no matter in decimals or directly to percentage, as long as the % is the same as in Excel column. Any ideas?

**P.S Left is Excel and right is PowerBI!**

[image]

Comment: Can you share your Excel formula? That will help me to see what is needed for the DAX.

Comment: @Jenn   Well I got only from Column E (Time difference) using **MOD(D3-D2;1)** 
and Column F (%) is just **= E2** with Percentage as Type of data. So not much of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Excel is basing the percentage on 24 hours, this I used in the calculation (24 hours = 24 * 3600 seconds).

I started combining in power query the date and the time, this has to do with the fact that you go over the day and your calculation still needs to be correct.

Go to query editor. select both columns, combine them. Next change the type to Date/Time, result:

[image]

Save and close editor.

In Power Bi, add a column:

```
NextDate = LOOKUPVALUE(Explog[Date];Explog[Index];Explog[Index] + 1)
```

This is picking up the next Date based on Index + 1

Add another column TimeDiffSec, calculating the datediff in seconds:

```
TimeDiffSec = DATEDIFF(Explog[Date];Explog[NextDate];SECOND)
```

Last step is adding a column for percentage:

```
% of time difference = 
var perc = Explog[TimeDiffSec]/ (24*3600)
return if(perc >= 1; perc -  1; perc)
```

End result:

[image]

*Note: If you have a situation you do not want to mix the System (STYRAX - scrubber) you can use the following for the NextDate:*

```
NextDate = 
var nextIndex = 
    CALCULATE(MIN(Explog[Index]);
        FILTER(Explog;Explog[Index] > EARLIER(Explog[Index]) && Explog[System] = EARLIER(Explog[System])))
return 
    LOOKUPVALUE(Explog[Date];Explog[Index];nextIndex; Explog[System];Explog[System])
```

Comment: This was quite helpful, it almost solved my problem!!  Just the percentage is showing slightly difference than mine in Excel..

The thing is those "Dates" have to be subtracted, like i did in Excel using MOD (A3-A2), so that I ignore that 24h difference overlap (from one day to another), when you subtracting like (18.01.2019 14:40 - 17.01.2019 04:55) it has to give 9:45:00 difference, but percentage has to be in this case 40,6% and I am getting 140,6% for those cases where I have this time overlap from one day to another.

Comment: In other words, it has to be under 100% per event. If I am doing it in your way, I am getting another picture of my data, which I will keep for comparison still.

Comment: I Updated teh percentages to not go over 100%

Comment: Amazing! Simply amazing! I wouldnt remember to use those "percs"...will have to learn it right now.  

It works like a charm now!! 

My big thanks!